# Increasing query performance for mysql longtext with like

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

As a production support developer looking for data in a mysql db, I often find myself querying a column which has type longtext and holds lots of data (100k+ rows each with 1000 characters or more of text). When I use the like operator with wildcards, my query often takes hours to return.

Is there anything I can do to my query or the table to speed this up?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the `longtext` column have a `fulltext` index on it?

Comment: Have you looked into full text indexing? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to properly ask a question... it will help you get an appropriate / better answer faster :)